# SQL Server 2008 Transaction Log: Date/Time

Tags: sql-server, transaction-log

Need to roll back a delete query, so I'm sifting through the transaction logs without really knowing what the meanings of most of the headers are.

TO ME, it looks like Current LSN, and possibly Transaction ID MIGHT be date or time but in a different format?

The Current LSN looks like this : 00000e46:00000a4d:0002
The Transaction ID looks like this: 0000:0000da25

Would I be wrong in thinking this? If so, does anyone know how I would be able to view the time/date in sql server transaction logs using ONLY SQL Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use ::fn_dblog

Now, I haven't tried using it myself but [some usage is described here](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/category/Transaction-Log.aspx#p18)

Answer (score 0):

If you want an easy approach, and don't mind paying, there is a commercial tool supporting SQL Server versions 2000, 2005, 2008, 2008 R2: [ApexSQL Log](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_log.aspx)